# Check if display sleep on Apple Silicon in Bash

Tags: terminal, bash, sleep-wake, script, apple-silicon

I have a Bash script that performs certain actions when the Mac enters sleep mode. The script worked fine on my Mac with an Intel chip, but it can't detect whether it's sleeping or not with Apple Silicon.

This is the part of the script:

```sh
commandSleepStatus='echo $(ioreg -n IODisplayWrangler | grep -i IOPowerManagement | perl -pe '\''s/^.*DevicePowerState"=([0-9]+).*$/\1/'\'')/4 | bc'
sleepStatus=$(eval "$commandSleepStatus")
# echo "$sleepStatus"

# Set isRunning to false if the sleep is active
if [ "$sleepStatus" -eq 0 ]; then
    isSleep=true
fi
```

The problem is with `ioreg -n IODisplayWrangler | grep -i IOPowerManagement`. It seems that Apple has removed `IOPowerManagement` from `ioreg` on Apple Silicon.

```
IODisplayWrangler  <class IODisplayWrangler, id 0x1000002a1, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 5>
    | |   {
    | |     "IOClass" = "IODisplayWrangler"
    | |     "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily"
    | |     "IOProviderClass" = "IOResources"
    | |     "IOGraphicsIgnoreParameters" = {"aupc"=Yes,"auph"=Yes," bpc"=Yes,"aums"=Yes,"aupp"=Yes}
    | |     "IOGraphicsPrefsParameters" = {"thue"=Yes,"pscn"=Yes,"vbst"=Yes,"oscn"=Yes,"tbri"=Yes,"cyuv"=268435456,"tsat"=Yes}
    | |     "IOResourceMatch" = "IOKit"
    | |     "IOProbeScore" = 0
    | |     "IOMatchCategory" = "IOGraphics"
    | |     "IOMatchedAtBoot" = Yes
    | |     "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
    | |     "IOPersonalityPublisher" = "com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily"
    | |     "CFBundleIdentifierKernel" = "com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily"
    | |   }
```

My question is whether there is another way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Please don‘t cross-post questions on several SE sites, have them migrated if necessary. Also, if you cross-post and self-answer, please make the full answer available on both sites to make sure it shows up in search.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe I have found a solution.

With Apple Silicon there isn't `IOPowerManagement` inside the `IODisplayWrangler` section. I had to look for the information in another way and I found `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType` Here, in fact, there is information about the integrated display and the external displays connected to the Mac. When the display goes into standby, an additional line `Display Asleep: Yes` appears which is not present when the display is on.

Here in the images you can see the differences:

[image]

[image]

I therefore wrote the following script which I will rewrite here in case anyone needs this information in the future.

```
#!/bin/bash

display_info=$(system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType)

count_asleep=$(echo "$display_info" | grep -c "Display Asleep: Yes")
count_awake=$(echo "$display_info" | grep -c "Display Asleep: No")

if [ $count_asleep -gt 0 ] && [ $count_awake -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

The script checks all the text and sees if the line `Display Asleep: Yes` is present. If this is present it prints `true` if instead one of the 2 is `Display Asleep: No` (It would not be necessary now but perhaps it will be added in the future ) or if not present prints `false`.

Comment: Could you add a bit of context as to how the script is initiated? Is it just constantly running in a terminal, or via `cron` or `launchd`? A more complete presentation, not just the detection bit, may make this more useful for other readers.

Comment: Not sure I understand the logic here. „Display Asleep“ can only be either „Yes“ or „No“, why test for both?

Comment: @AndyGriffiths I have update the answer

Comment: Please see [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Comment: The script can be shortened to `if system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep -q "Display Asleep: Yes"; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small Objective-C program that may be helpful.

It will return the current display sleep/wake status or the screen lock status via exit code (`0`=sleeping/locked, `1`=awake/unlocked).

#### Tiny examples

```bash
dstat -s || echo "your screen is awake"

if ! dstat --lock ; then
  echo "hey your screen is unlocked!"
fi
```

When I benchmarked this tool with [`hyperfine`](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine) on my M1 Mac Mini, I found it to be much more efficient than parsing the output of `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep ...`

| Test | Time |
| --- | --- |
| `dstat -l` | 4.7ms |
| `dstat -s` | 30.8ms |
| `system_profiler ... | grep ...` | 534.6ms |

The tool is built as a Universal Binary and is self-contained. The source, binary, and a few more examples are on GitHub: [luckman212/dstat](https://github.com/luckman212/dstat).

Comment: I don't question the fact that it is much faster with your method but this implies having to install additional dependencies. In fact I need a solution that is written in bash without the need for additional dependencies or packages.